# How to fix texture mapping?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have the house, and bricks texture. Howewer, the texture seems not be correctly located on the different parts of the house body. picture

So, I'd like to do some mapping with the bricks texture. But if I scale or rotate the texture, it looks the same as in the picture.
[image: problem]

Comment: You should modify the UV map for that.

Comment: The _Mapping_ node affects all coordinates you plugged in there uniformly, but obviously the front and side faces of the house are oriented differently, so whatever you do might correct one side but mess up the other side. Since you are using the UV coordinates you have to edit the UV map to orient both faces in the same direction. The scaling is different compared to each other as well. You have to edit the UV map or maybe create a new one. I would highly recommend you watch tutorials on UV unwrapping, UV mapping and texturing.

Comment: Thanks, I will just try to fix the UV and find some tutirials.